# error TS2305: Module '"@nestjs/typeorm"' has no exported member 'getRepositoryToken'

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, package.json

I've been messing around with packages version of Nestjs and TypeOrm, and I have fallen in a rabbit hole of TS errors.

I've solved many but one is persistant and I can't figure out how to solve it:

```
src/workout/workout.module.ts:2:10 - error TS2305: Module '"@nestjs/typeorm"' has no exported member 'getRepositoryToken'.

2 import { getRepositoryToken, TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/workout/workout.module.ts:2:30 - error TS2305: Module '"@nestjs/typeorm"' has no exported member 'TypeOrmModule'.

2 import { getRepositoryToken, TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
```

The source code being:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { getRepositoryToken, TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import { WorkoutResolver } from './workout.resolver'
import { WorkoutService } from './workout.service'
import { TypeOrmExerciseTemplateRepository } from '../exercise/repositories/type-orm-exercise-template.repository'
import { TypeOrmWorkoutRepository } from './repositories/workout.typeorm.repository'
import { TypeOrmExerciseRepository } from '../exercise/repositories/type-orm-exercise.repository'
import { WORKOUT_REPOSITORY } from './repositories/workout.repository.interface'
import { EXERCISE_TEMPLATE_REPOSITORY } from '../exercise/repositories/exercise-template-repository.interface'
import { EXERCISE_REPOSITORY } from '../exercise/repositories/exercise-repository.interface'
import { TypeOrmSessionRepository } from '../session/repositories/session.typeorm.repository'
import { FillWorkoutWithExercisesUseCase } from './use-cases/fill-workout-with-exercises.use-case'
import { PROGRAM_REPOSITORY } from '../program/repositories/program-repository.interface'
import { TypeOrmProgramRepository } from '../program/repositories/type-orm-program.repository'

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      TypeOrmExerciseTemplateRepository,
      TypeOrmExerciseRepository,
      TypeOrmWorkoutRepository,
      TypeOrmSessionRepository,
      TypeOrmProgramRepository,
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: WORKOUT_REPOSITORY,
      useExisting: getRepositoryToken(TypeOrmWorkoutRepository),
    },
    {
      provide: EXERCISE_REPOSITORY,
      useExisting: getRepositoryToken(TypeOrmExerciseRepository),
    },
    {
      provide: EXERCISE_TEMPLATE_REPOSITORY,
      useExisting: getRepositoryToken(TypeOrmExerciseTemplateRepository),
    },
    {
      provide: PROGRAM_REPOSITORY,
      useExisting: getRepositoryToken(TypeOrmProgramRepository),
    },
    WorkoutResolver,
    WorkoutService,
    FillWorkoutWithExercisesUseCase,
  ],
})
export class WorkoutModule {}
```

My typeorm and nestjs/typeorm version are:

```
    "typeorm": "^0.3.12",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "nestjs/typeorm",
```

The full dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/gateway": "^0.51.0",
    "@nestjs/apollo": "^10.0.19",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.6.15",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.6.15",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^10.0.21",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.2.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.15",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "nestjs/typeorm",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.6",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "env-var": "^7.3.0",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^8.3.3",
    "knex": "^2.2.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7",
    "ts-morph": "^15.1.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.12"
  },
```

Comment: Why do you have this dependency as `"@nestjs/typeorm": "nestjs/typeorm"`? I'd strongly recommend you `npm un @nestjs/typeorm; npm i @nestjs/typeorm` and take whatever version npm downloads for you. Because that function definitely exists https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgcwKYwEqsgZ2DaATwBUIBrVAOwBo5jCxUB5KEAWQgBMBXAG1TgBfOADMoEEHADkAAUqocMAFY4A9DAapoIKQChVquEeNwAegH4gA which means you aren't getting the code you think you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's the fact that you're pulling nestjs/typeorm from GitHub (I believe that's what happens with that kind of import) which doesn't end up having the proper file that the main of the package.json references because it's the ts source code and not the js compiled code

Actually install `@nestjs/typeorm` from npm and it should be fine

Answer (score -1):

Well spotted @alex-wayne !

A yarn add @nestjs/typeorm@latest fixed my issue by getting a classic version number, thanks